# bash export not working for only one variable

Tags: bash

Occasionally when I export in bash it doesn't give an error but it doesn't set the environment variable either. Here's what I mean:

This works:

```
bash-3.2$ export DYLD=$ABC_HOME
bash-3.2$ env | grep DYLD
DYLD=/Users/my_username/abc_home
```

But when I continue, these don't:

```
bash-3.2$ export DYLD_LIBRARY=$ABC_HOME
bash-3.2$ env | grep DYLD
DYLD=/Users/my_username/abc_home

bash-3.2$ export DYLD_L=$ABC_HOME
bash-3.2$ env | grep DYLD
DYLD=/Users/my_username/abc_home

bash-3.2$ export DYLD_=$ABC_HOME
bash-3.2$ env | grep DYLD
DYLD=/Users/my_username/abc_home
```

Any idea what I could look at to fix this?

FWIW, other exports with underscores work as expected, but this seems to start failing once I add the underscore in.

Comment: I don't see that here. What OS is this? OS X I presume? Does this work correctly with non-`DYLD` prefixes? Could this be an OS X "protection"?

Comment: I get a slightly different behavior on an OS X machine, but it suggests there's something special about `DYLD` names: $ env | grep DYLD
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_L
dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY

Comment: Do curly braces make any difference: `${ABC_HOME}`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24320548/1517864)

Comment: This is really strange! I never noticed this (OS X). It seems to have to do with the specific DYLD prefix. It does not happen with DYLE* etc.

Comment: Do you see the exported variables if you use the `export` command to view rhem, rather than `env`?

Comment: @rici I do see them when I use `export`. Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yup I'm on OS X 10.11.1. I suspect that it's an El Capitan protection because it used to work on earlier versions.

Comment: [This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9233) seems fairly relevant.

Comment: @jjjkkklllhhh: I think the link @Etan posted is relevant, but my original idea (which is partially confirmed by your answer) is that environment variables starting `DYLD_` are being cleaned from the environment by the installed version of `env` (or by something else).

Comment: The link seems to indicate that they are being scrubbed from the environment of "protected processes" among which is the shell. So while `export` marks them for export to bash internally it fails to set them in the actual process environment (so `env` doesn't see them).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yeah, there is actually documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). According to that, "When system files are installed, they are marked with a special flag to protect against modification..." Also, directories like `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are automatically protected. Finally, "[a]ny dynamic linker ( dyld ) environment variables, such as DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, are purged when launching protected processes." Here, I think the issue is that `env` is protected.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Sadly, I no longer have a Mac to play with.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I wonder if `env` or the shell is protected/at "fault" here. @jjjkkklllhhh Do you see the `DYLD_`, etc. values in the output of `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$$/environ | grep DYLD`?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be an OS X protection (added in El Capitan possibly) that prevents these (potentially dangerous) environment variables from being exported to spawned processes.

[This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9233) on the Apple Developer Forums discuss this some.

The official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH3-SW1) also documents this briefly:

> Spawning children processes of processes restricted by System Integrity Protection, such as by launching a helper process in a bundle with `NSTask` or calling the `exec(2)` command, resets the Mach special ports of that child process. Any dynamic linker (`dyld`) environment variables, such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, are purged when launching protected processes.

Comment: This is indeed added in El Capitan, and can be disabled from the recovery partition with `csrutil enable --without debug` (the `--without` option is undocumented).

Comment: @4ae1e1 That disables the feature entirely? Is there control over whether a specific executable is in the protected/restricted set?

Comment: There is `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf`, but I believe it's undocumented, and the conf file itself is under Filesystem Protection of SIP (so you'll have to `--without filesystem` first to make any changes to it; even then I'm not sure if changes would be picked up, since I never tried).

Comment: Found [this Apple Developer Forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16768) with some QA allegedly from WWDC Security and Privacy Lab.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
export DYLD_LIBRARY=$ABC_HOME
env | grep DYLD
IFS=$oldifs
```

Comment: Why do you think that will help? (Add the explanation to your answer.)