# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't show up in env?

Tags: macos, bash, dyld

I'm struggling to debug an issue with libraries failing to load. The obvious solution is to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory that contains the libraries, however for some reason this solution doesn't seem to be taking. I do:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path>
```

but the variable doesn't appear when I call `env`. Strangely enough, it does tab-complete, as in when I do `echo $DYLD_<tab>`. What gives?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/me; env | grep DYLD` shows the variable.

Comment: Worth having a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33616185/258523 though that doesn't have an accepted answer at the moment. I'm about to migrate the comments into an answer on it though.