# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be used by python's os and subprocess modules on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, ld, macos-sierra

On macOS Sierra 10.12.6, environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` cannot be used by `os.system()`, `subprocess.run()` and `subprocess.Popen()`, even though `PATH` can be used normally. Python version is `3.6.1`. But on Linux(Ubuntu 17.10), this environment variable can also be used rightly. The following python script `envv.py` can show this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os
import time

PATH = "PATH"
print(os.environ.get(PATH))
os.system("echo $" + PATH)
subprocess.run("echo $" + PATH, shell=True)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + PATH, shell=True)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + PATH, shell=True, env={PATH: os.environ.get(PATH)})
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ)
subprocess.Popen("/bin/echo $" + PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ.copy())
time.sleep(2)
print('\n')

LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
print(os.environ.get(LD_LIBRARY_PATH))
os.system("echo $" + LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + LD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + LD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env={LD_LIBRARY_PATH: os.environ.get(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)})
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + LD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ)
subprocess.Popen("/bin/echo $" + LD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ.copy())
time.sleep(2)
print('\n')
```

On macOS, the output is

```
$ python3 envv.py 
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...
/opt/alps/bin:...


/opt/alps/lib:...
$    # use $ to show blank line
$
....
```

On Linux, the output is

```
$ python3 envv.py 
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/bin/intel64:...


/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:...
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 2018-02-07**

Follow @GrahamDumpleton 's suggestion, I tried `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but got the same result. The test stript is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import os

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
print(os.environ.get(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH))
os.system("echo $" + DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True)
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env={DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: os.environ.get(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)})
subprocess.run("/bin/echo $" + DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ)
subprocess.Popen("/bin/echo $" + DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, shell=True, env=os.environ.copy())
```

And the related output is

```
$ python3 envv.py
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/compiler/lib:...
$
$
...
```

Comment: On macOS for indicating where shared libraries can be loaded, it is ``DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`` and not ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` for a start. So any behaviour seen shouldn't be specific to that variable name, so try with a different variable name. If ``DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`` is used, there are some strange places where it doesn't get inherited on macOS, but you aren't using that name.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for your comment. I have tried `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` but got the same result as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. And I have updated the question.

Comment: Now read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH3-SW1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616185/bash-export-not-working-for-only-one-variable I only expect it to apply to DYLD_* variables though, not LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9233 is related to this problem. In practice, what I want is a python wrapper for a numerical simulation program which is written by Fortran and MKL library is used dynamically. I use `subprocess.run("FORTRAN_PROG.exe")` to run the program, so `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True`, you can manually propagate the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables like so:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

cmd = "/bin/echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

sys_env = os.environ.copy()

# We've used os.environ.copy() so we can make mods
# to the subprocess environment if needed without
# affecting the parent process.

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    if "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" in sys_env:
        cmd = f"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH={sys_env['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']} && {cmd}"
    if "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" in sys_env:
        cmd = f"export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH={sys_env['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH']} && {cmd}"

process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    env=sys_env,
    shell=True,
)
```